# How can I add 'blog.site_name.com' to urls.py in Django

Tags: django, django-urls, django-1.5, django-1.6

How can we add 'blog.site_name.com' or such types of url in Django instead of 'site_name.com/blog/' to urls.py in Django? I want to make URLs like 'mail.google.com', 'drive.google.com'. How can we make such urls in Django? Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at [django-subdomains](https://github.com/tkaemming/django-subdomains) or [django-hosts](https://github.com/jezdez/django-hosts) package.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two `urlconf` files, one for `site_name.com`, another for `blog.site_name.com`. 
Then you make a custom middleware that will switch the `urlconf` based on domain name. See [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request) for details.